# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error but why

Tags: python, types, typeerror

So i have this code that works

```
import random
password = 0

print("Password Generator")

app = str(input("For what application would you like to generate a password\n"))
n = int(input("How many characters would you like in your password?\n"))

chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','!','@','#','$']

password = random.choice(chars)
i = 0

for i in range(n-1):
    password = password + random.choice(chars)

print(f"Your password is: {password}")

with open('passwordlist.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{app} : {password}\n")
```

But if I put an input above app input it does not work why

```
import random
password = 0

print("Password Generator")

input = input("What would you like to do?\n")

app = str(input("For what application would you like to generate a password\n"))
n = int(input("How many characters would you like in your password?\n"))

chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','!','@','#','$']

password = random.choice(chars)
i = 0

for i in range(n-1):
    password = password + random.choice(chars)

print(f"Your password is: {password}")

with open('passwordlist.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{app} : {password}\n")
```

So i tried changing the variable name , changed where the string was but it does not work

Comment: Once you use `input` as a variable name, you can no longer use the builtin function `input`. So you get an error when trying to get input from the user.

Comment: This line `input = input("What would you like to do?\n")` shadows the built-in function `input()` with a string in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

with this line:

```
input = input("What would you like to do?\n")
```

you are overriding the main functionality of `input`, instead you are putting a string in it. and in the next two lines you are using it.

some names are pre-defined in python, do not use them as variable names.
so just change the variable name in that line to:

```
user_input = input("What would you like to do?\n")
```